# Preventing Duplicates based on two or more columns in a Sharepoint List with C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I am having problems with preventing duplicates based on two or more columns in a Sharepoint Foundation environment. My idea is to create an event handler in C# to intercept the creation of a item in a list an check if the combination of two columns exists in the list already and send an error if it exists.

So the basic idea is: in List A, a booking list, I have column A (Time) and column B (Date). When the item is going to be created I want to have an event handler that intercepts the creation and checks if Time+Date already exists in the List so a double booking can't occur.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are on the right track in implementing an [ItemAdding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadding.aspx) Event Receiver.

For examples on how to create an Event Receiver see:

- [Example: Creating a List Item Event Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437502.aspx)
- [How to: Create an Event Handler Feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453149.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Change your query parameters, like this:

```
query.Query = @"<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Time' /><Value Type='Choise'>" +
                                 properties.AfterProperties["Time"] + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value Type='Choise'>" +
                                  properties.AfterProperties["Date"] + "</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
```